# Limit users read/write access to firebase nodes is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, firebase-security

I have a firebase database structure with a few root nodes (for this question only a few are important): **buildings** and **buildingsUserId** (the intent of **buildingsUserUid** is to control the access of the users to their buildings and their buildings only).

If we dive a little deeper into the structure of both nodes we have the following:

```
users
  `-- userID // one user can access this 
  |   `-- isAdmin
  |       `-- building pushkey
  |       `-- another building pushkey etc.
  `-- another userID // one user can access this 
  |   `-- isAdmin
  |       `-- building pushkey
  |       `-- another building pushkey etc.
  `-- another user UID etc.


buildingsUserUid
  `-- firebase user UID // one user can access this 
  |   `-- building pushkey
  |   `-- another building pushkey
  `-- another firebase user UID // another user can access this 
      `-- yet another building pushkey 
      `-- and another building pushkey etc.

buildings
 `-- building pushkeys // user with right UID can access this
 |   |-- firebase user UID
 |   `-- Other data
 `-- building pushkeys  //another user with right UID can access this
     |-- firebase user UID
     `-- Other data
```

Then my firebase rules are like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid",
          }
      },
      "buildings": {
         ".read": "root.child('buildingsUserUid').hasChild(auth.uid)",
         ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildingsUserUid').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            "$pushkey": {
                ".read": "root.child('buildingsUserUid').child(auth.uid).hasChild($pushkey)",
                ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildingsUserUid').child(auth.uid).hasChild($pushkey)",
             }
      },
      "buildingsUserUid": {
         "$user": {
             ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $user",
             ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $user"
          }
      },
 }
```

With the rules above I was hoping to limit the access to the building nodes to only the user that had the building pushkey on its buildingsUserUid node. However if I **console.log(this)** on my vue.js app I can see all the buildings.

[image]

Is this because I'm logging **this** from the App or would a user be able to access **this** the same way from the browser console? Am I missing something in my rules?

UPDATE:

Following @Umar answer, I've changed my rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth != null && $uid === auth.uid",
          }
      },
      "buildings": {
         ".read": "root.child('buildingsUserUid').hasChild(auth.uid)",
         ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildingsUserUid').hasChild(auth.uid)",
            "$pushkey": {
                // changed the following 'read' rule line
                ".read": "root.child('buildingsUserUid').child($pushkey).child('userId') === auth.uid"
                ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildingsUserUid').child(auth.uid).hasChild($pushkey)",
             }
      },
      "buildingsUserUid": {
         "$user": {
             ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === $user",
             ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $user"
          }
      },
 }
```

But this triggers the error:

> Error saving rules – Line 15: Invalid == expression: left operand is not a number, boolean, string, null. –

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

By putting `".read": "root.child('buildingsUserUid').hasChild(auth.uid)"` to `buildings` you are essentially allowing any user of any building to read all the building nodes data.

You have to allow read access one level below i.e. under `pushkey`. Also if you are associating only one user to one building you can simply store building id under user node instead of under pushkey of building.

for your current structure `pushkey` read can be

`".read": "root.child('buildingsUserUid').child($pushkey).child('userId') === auth.uid"`

I'm assuming that you have one user per building and user's uid is stored with key userId under 'pushkey'

Comment: Thanks @Umar. I am associating one user to several buildings (those buildings could eventually be shared by several users).
Would this rule still work? Just to be completely sure that new line would be placed under __buildings__ rules or under __buildings/$pushkey__?

Comment: I am assuming under __buildings/$pushkey__ like so: `"buildings": {
      ".read": "root.child('buildingsUserUid').hasChild(auth.uid)",
      ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildingsUserUid').hasChild(auth.uid)",
      "$pushkey": {
        ".read": "root.child('buildingsUserUid').child($pushkey).child('userId') == auth.uid",
        ".write": "!data.exists() || root.child('buildingsUserUid').child(auth.uid).hasChild($pushkey)",
      }
    },` but this is causing error `Error saving rules – Line 15: Invalid == expression: left operand is not a number, boolean, string, null.`

Comment: If you want to associate one user to several buildings then this structure will not work efficiently. For example you will need to get all the buildings of a user but you don't want to allow other users to know this relationship. What you can do is nest a buildings node under each user and add a buildingId when you want to add a building to a user. Then you can open the root Buildings node for read safely.

Comment: Hi @Umar! I have actually already preemptively built the app with such nodes: __users/isAdmin/buildingID__. I thought __buildingsUserUid__ and __buildings__  nodes would be enough to solve this so I've just posted it here. I'm adding the Users node structure to the question and maybe you could help me with the rules with that. Many thanks for your input so far.